# Sort Array of Objects having decimal/dotted numbers

Tags: javascript, sorting

how can I sort the below array in ascending order in JS?

```
let obj_list = [{Sno:"1"},{Sno:"4"},{Sno:"3"},{Sno:"9"},{Sno:"9.1"},
                {Sno:"9.2"},{Sno:"9.6"},{Sno:"9.3"},{Sno:"9.10"},
                {Sno:"9.11"},{Sno:"9.13"},{Sno:"9.12"}];
```

I tried the normal sort function as written below, but the output was coming incorrect

```
obj_list.sort(function(a,b){
return a.Sno - b.Sno;
});
```

UPDATING the Post:

I am expecting the output as:

```
[{Sno:"1"},{Sno:"3"},{Sno:"4"},{Sno:"9"},{Sno:"9.1"},
{Sno:"9.2"},{Sno:"9.3"},{Sno:"9.6"},{Sno:"9.10"},
{Sno:"9.11"},{Sno:"9.12"},{Sno:"9.13"}]
```

Comment: idk why you dont got answer. it just ```obj_list.sort((a,b) => a.Sno - b.Sno);```

Comment: @HassanImam,@danhuong
I have updated the post for my expected output. Thanks

Comment: What makes 9.2 < 9.10 ?

Comment: Use `obj_list.sort((a,b) => a.Sno.localeCompare(b.Sno, undefined, { numeric:true }))`

Answer (score -1):

Here your answer please check it thanks.

```js
let obj_list = [{ Sno: "1" }, { Sno: "4" }, { Sno: "3" }, { Sno: "9" }, { Sno: "9.1" },
    { Sno: "9.2" }, { Sno: "9.6" }, { Sno: "9.3" }, { Sno: "9.10" },
    { Sno: "9.11" }, { Sno: "9.13" }, { Sno: "9.12" }
];



obj_list.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a["Sno"];
    var y = b["Sno"];
    return x - y;
});
var without_decimal = obj_list.filter(o => o.Sno.split(".").length == 1);
obj_list = obj_list.filter(o => o.Sno.split(".").length > 1).sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a["Sno"].split(".")[1] + "0";
    var y = b["Sno"].split(".")[1] + "0";
    return x - y;
});
var result = without_decimal.concat(obj_list);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please check the expected output. They want `9.10` after `9.2`

Comment: Sorry now only i saw, i will check and update u

Comment: Check the output now

Comment: `without_decimal.concat(obj_list)` will not work. If there is `Sno: "10"`, it will be added before all the `9.x`

Comment: great you are correct